# Testing Nullables with PersistenceSpecification

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Is it possible to test Nullable Types with PersistenceSpecification?

```
var approved = new Nullable<DateTime>();
spec.CheckProperty(x => x.Approved, approved);
```

Currently this throws a NullReferenceException.  Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is possible indeed.

1. Is approved of type `Nullable<DateTime>?`
2. Have you created your own IEqualityComparer?
3. Could you provide some more code for us to help you?

Comment: Yes, Approved is Nullable. Not using an IEqualityComparer implementation.

Comment: The problems with dates in .NET is that two date instances having the same value is not equal by default. Ex. date1 = '2009-01-01', date2 = '2009-01-01' but date1 != date2. Hence you need to implement your own IEqualityComparer so that you can compare the actual values inside the datetime like year, month and so on.